# Tricky SQL when joining

Tags: sql, mysql

I've two tables, shows, and objects. I want to print out the latest objects, and the shownames for them. Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
SELECT MAX(objects.id) as max_id, shows.name, shows.id 
FROM shows, objects 
WHERE shows.id = objects.showId
GROUP BY shows.name
```

However, if I also want to fetch the episode of the object I can't put it like `SELECT object.episode [...]`, because then won't automatically select the object which is `MAX(objects.id)`, so my question is how to do that?

If you haven't already figured out my tables they're like this:

- Shows

  - Id
  - Name

And also:

- Objects

  - Id
  - Name
  - Episode
  - Season
  - showId

Using MySQL.

Comment: Is performance an issue? How many rows do you have in each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT objects.id as max_id, objects.episode, shows.name, shows.id
  FROM shows, objects 
 WHERE shows.id = objects.showId
   AND objects.id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM objects
         WHERE name = shows.name
       )
```

Comment: that does indeed work! however the WHERE-clause should be in ids. Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think that `=` should work just as well as `IN` (Is this what you meant?) and may be faster since it gives a hint to the optimiser that only one row is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT objects.id as max_id, shows.name, shows.id 
FROM shows, objects 
WHERE shows.id = objects.showId
ORDER BY objects.id DESC
GROUP BY shows.name 
LIMIT 1
```

Does that do what you need?

Comment: This only returns one object. The OP wants the most recent object for each name and the related episode.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling something like this would work also:

```
SELECT objects.id, objects.episode, shows.name, shows.id 
FROM shows 
JOIN objects AS objects_for_max ON shows.id = objects.showId
JOIN objects ON objects.id=MAX(objects_for_max.id)
GROUP BY shows.name
```